# resize Image with less loss in C#

Tags: c#

In my project, i have to reduce the image size with C# program by entering percentage.

> However, something wrong:
>
> **image format:** TIF
>
> **original image:** 6MB with 1920*1080
>
> **resized image:**  27KB with 1728*972
>
> **scale down to** 90%

It shoud not be 27KB, but > 5MB...

Code

```
    public Image reduce(Image sourceImage, string size)
    {
        var original = sourceImage;
        //store image widths in variable for easier use
        var oW = (decimal)original.Width;
        var oH = (decimal)original.Height;
        var dW = (decimal)desiredWidth;
        var dH = (decimal)desiredHeight;
        var dR = (decimal)Int32.Parse(size);;

        var nH = oH * (dR / 100); 
        var nW = oW * (dR / 100);

        var resized = new Bitmap((int)nW, (int)nH);
        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(sourceImage))
        {
            gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            gr.DrawImage(resized, new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)nH, (int)nW));
        }

        return resized;
    }
```

any ideas?

**update**

```
              Image nImage = imagetool.reduce(originalImg, size);
                  
              byte[] nImageData = imagetool.imageToByteArray(nImage);
                  
              int nImageSize = nImageData.Length;
              Console.WriteLine("new image size " + nImageSize );


               try
               {
                  Console.WriteLine("trying to update the image in sharepoint");
                        
                  web.Files.Add(Path.Combine(itemsite, itemSubsite, fileURL), nImageData, true);
               }
```

**update 2**

```
    public byte[] imageToByteArray(Image imageIn)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            if (imageIn.RawFormat.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg))
            {
                imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
            if (imageIn.RawFormat.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png))
            {
                imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
            if (imageIn.RawFormat.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp))
            {
                imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
            if (imageIn.RawFormat.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif))
            {
                imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
            if (imageIn.RawFormat.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff))
            {
                imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
            else
            {
                imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: any ideas about *what* - what is your question?

Comment: Are you still saving it as a tif? or something else? does the image actually look OK when done?

Comment: @BugFinder it is tif image, and it looks good

Comment: Add the code where you save the picture to you question also.

Comment: @Jamiec Do you thing that it is OK if you enter reducing 10% for a 8k (7MB) image, than receive a 30KB image?

Comment: @mortb i am uploading those images to cloud (SharePoint)

Comment: @kingyau where does the 8K image come from? Your original was supposedly 6Mb. If what you say in your comment is right, its because you're using a different compression format (eg, Original Jpg and output is BMP)

Comment: How do you calculate the size of the resized image?

Comment: @kingyau: where is the code where you upload the image then? Somehow you must write the image either to a file or a stream. We need the code that does that.

Comment: @mortb please check my update

Comment: Please post a link to an example input image and a [mcve]. You haven't posted the code that saves the image so it is impossible to say why the *saved* image is only 27KiB.

Comment: @Jamiec the problem is that it also returns 30KB image if the user is uploading a 8K image (7MB)...

Comment: That still doesnt help - when you save a image file you invariably give it an `ImageFormat` - such as `myImage.Save("somefile.tif",ImageFormat.Tiff)`.

Comment: @kingyau: we need the code in `imageToByteArray`

Comment: @mortb please check my update

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen you can see how i count the image size in above code. key word: nImageSize.

Comment: Have you stepped through the imageToByteArray code to make sure it is going into the Bmp format rather than any of the compressed formats.

Comment: When you debug this and step through I assume `imageToByteArray` is picking up the right image type for the original. In my head, it would always be a `bmp`, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @PaulF i don't know what you mean for?.... Input a BMP format image?

Comment: Again, please post a [mcve].

Comment: In the reduce method you are creating a Bitmap image - which is Bmp format.

Comment: @PaulF The same problem with BMP format, 3MB => 3xKB with reducing 10%..

Comment: Debug your code and verify which of the save branches is taken. I'm going to bet it takes the else part and saves it as a jpeg because you're saving a new image that doesn't have a format yet.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen i am creating a memo application

Comment: instead off all those ifs, you can just do `imageIn.Save(ms, imageIn.RawFormat);`

Comment: It doesn't matter what kind of application you're making. The bitmap you're saving is a `new Bitmap(...)`, it doesn't have a RawFormat yet that matches your if-statements (specifically it has a value of `ImageFormat.MemoryBMP`). Your code ends up saving as a .jpeg because of this. Please debug your application and verify how you're saving it. The act of creating a [mcve] would've given you a hint of this.

Answer (score 0):

`nImage` 
is created in other place at

```
var resized = new Bitmap((int)nW, (int)nH)
```

and its format is not TIFF and code finishes at:

```
 else
        {
            imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: Because the `RawFormat` is not equal to the Bmp format for a new Bitmap object. A `new Bitmap(...)` have a `RawFormat` value that corresponds to `MemoryBMP`.

Answer (score 0):

Your new image does not have any format, it is not read automatically from your original when you create the new `Bitmap` object, and thus is being written out as a jpg, (from the final `else` part of your code)

The way to solve this problem is to pass into `imageToByteArray` the original format, and use that when writing the new image to your `MemoryStream`. You can also do away with the long `if..else` block

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(Image imageIn, ImageFormat format)
{
    using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        imageIn.Save(ms,format);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
 }
```

And your calling code should be

```
byte[] nImageData = imagetool.imageToByteArray(nImage, originalImg.RawFormat);
```